# JavaScript count-down-timer with sopporting cancel and restart

Tags: javascript

Here i have a simple `javascript` which i want to making a simple `CountDownTimer` with cancel and restarting features, unfortunately after starting timer using `setInterval` that's return only `4` number in console and i can't fix that. without assuming this problem `clearInterval` not working to which i want to support cancel and restart again this time

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fiveMinutes = 5, display = document.querySelector('#time');
    let myTimer = function (){
        let timer = fiveMinutes, minutes, seconds;
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        if (--timer < 0) {
            $('#resend').show();
            $('#time').hide();
            clearInterval(this);
        }
        console.log(timer);
    };
    $('#startTimer').on('click', function(){
        $('#resend').hide();
        $('#time').show();
        setInterval(myTimer , 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `setInterval` returns a numeric id, which is why you are getting 4; `clearInterval` takes the id that is returned by `setInterval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fixed below. The main problem was `fiveMinutes` permanently being reassigned to 5, which I solved with a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). Also it was not multiplied by 60 to be converted in seconds.

```js
const display = document.querySelector('#time');

let interval;

function myTimer (timer) {
  return function () {
    let minutes, seconds;
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (--timer < 0) {
      $('#resend').show();
      $('#time').hide();
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    console.log(timer);
  }

};
$('#startTimer').on('click', function () {
  $('#resend').hide();
  $('#time').show();
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(myTimer(5 * 60), 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
<button id="startTimer">Start</button>
```